# How to do a vector product in VHDL

Tags: vhdl, fpga

How would I go about doing a vector product in VHDL?

e.g. I have 2 vectors defined like so:

```
type array_4_8bit is array (0 to 3) of std_logic_vector(7 downto 0);
signal Array_Last4Vals : array_4_8bit;
signal Multiplier : array_4_8bit;
Array_Last4Vals <= [5, 6, 7, 8]; -- will replace these numbers with the corresponding binary numbers
Multiplier <= [1, 2, 3, 4]; -- will replace these numbers with the corresponding binary numbers
product <= Multiplier*Array_Last4Vals;
```

I then want the product to be [5, 12, 21, 32] in this example.

How would I go about doing that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

VHDL allows re-definition of infix operators, like `*`, for custom types, so you can declare a function that does the vector multiplication like:

```
function "*"(a, b : array_4_8bit) return array_4_8bit is
  variable result_v : array_4_8bit;
begin
  for idx in result_v'range loop
    result_v(idx) := std_logic_vector(unsigned(a(idx)) * unsigned(b(idx)));
  end loop;
  return result_v;
end function;
```

Assumption above is that he vector elements are unsigned values, and that the result of each multiplication is truncated to 8 bits.

For generation of the input data, you can also consider doing:

```
type array_4_integer is array (0 to 3) of integer;

function to_array_4_8bit(v : array_4_integer) return array_4_8bit is
  variable result_v : array_4_8bit;
begin
  for idx in result_v'range loop
    result_v(idx) := std_logic_vector(to_unsigned(v(idx), 8));
  end loop;
  return result_v;
end function;

Array_Last4Vals <= to_array_4_8bit((5, 6, 7, 8));
Multiplier <= to_array_4_8bit((1, 2, 3, 4));
```

Comment: Thanks, that's really helpful. Is there a way to know if the resulting multiplication will be implemented on the FPGA as sequential multiplications or as parallel multiplications? This needs to be fast for large vectors (maybe up to a couple of hundred elements)

Comment: If using the function, then the result will be purely combinatorical, thus in parallel (and fast), since there is no clock that can be used to generate the result through a sequential design, and the synthesis tools cant do that by them selves.

Comment: Brilliant! Thanks!