# How to find dot product of two vectors in vhdl?

Tags: vhdl, product, xilinx

I am new to VHDL. I am trying to design a generic code for vectors dot or scalar product on Xilinx FPGA. Suppose we have a vector two vectors of

```
V1=[1,4,5,1] and V2=[3,6,9,1].
```

We can find it using

```
V1.V2=(1x3)+(4x6)+(5x9)+(1x1)=73
```

```
library IEEE;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.ALL;
use IEEE.numeric_std.ALL;

entity dot_product is
    Port ( vector_x : in STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (3 downto 0);
           vector_y : in STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (3 downto 0);
           r0 : out STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (3 downto 0);
           r1 : out STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (3 downto 0);
           r2 : out STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (3 downto 0);
           result : out STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (7 downto 0));
end dot_product;

architecture Behavioral of dot_product is

begin
r0 <= std_logic_vector(signed(vector_x(0)* vector_y(0)));
r1 <= std_logic_vector(signed(vector_x(1)* vector_y(1)));
r2 <= std_logic_vector(signed(vector_x(2)* vector_y(2)));
r3 <= std_logic_vector(signed(vector_x(3)* vector_y(3)));
result<=r0+r1+r2+r3;

end Behavioral;
```

How can we find its dot product in VHDL and later I can change vector size according to my requirement. Please help. Thanks:)

Comment: VHDL is not Matlab. You just have to write the code to do the additions and multiplications you need. If you're not too fussed about speed/area, you can use the `+` and `*` operators and take what the synthesiser gives you. If you are, you are going to have to put some thought into how you want to implement your addition and multiplication in hardware.

Comment: Thanks for your comments. I know basic about how to multiply and add in VHDL. I am a bit confused about access vector elements to perform above function. If you could help me, that would be great.

Comment: Then I don't understand what you are asking. You would presumably store your vectors in VHDL arrays. There is no dot product operator in VHDL. (There may be some package somewhere that implements such a thing, I don't know.) So, you need to either find such a package (which probably does not exist) or to write the code yourself. If you have already written such code and have a specific problem with it, then please ask a specific question about that.

Comment: @MatthewTaylor I have updated my question. Please consider me as begineer to VHDL. I know I am doing it wrong. Please help me. Thanks:)

Comment: Its still unclear from the code what you're trying to do, as the example values could not be stored in the way you seemed to store them, and its not vlear how R0/1/2 relate to the dot product calculation. You also have errors because `vector_x(0)` is a single std_logic value, and there is no standard function for `std_logic * std_logic`. You're trying to do a 1bit value multiplied by another 1 bit value? I think you need to separate your maths problem from learning VHDL. VHDL can be used like any other language, but it is usually aimed at hardware applications. So far your is not the latter.

Comment: See [How to do a vector product in VHDL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37861806/how-to-do-a-vector-product-in-vhdl) which demonstrates everything except your `result<=r0+r1+r2+r3;`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These are some notes:

> - vector_x : in STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (3 downto 0);

this is not a vector as in math. It is a an array of bits zeros and ones. so you can use it to represent numbers from 0 (0000) to 15 (1111).

if you want to have a vector, consider declaring an array of std_logic_vector.

> type t_vector is array (integer range <>) of std_logic_vector(3 downto 0);

consider reading this: https://www.nandland.com/vhdl/examples/example-array-type-vhdl.html

then you declare your vectors as an array with type t_vector.

after that, you can use for loop in a process to do the multiplication and addition.
consider reading this: http://habeebq.github.io/writing-a-2x2-matrix-multiplier-in-vhdl.html

to have a generic array size, consider using an unconstrained array or generic for the size.

```
entity dot_product is
    generic (width : positive := 8);
    port (vector_x : in t_vector (width downto 0);
          vector_y : in t_vector (width downto 0);
            result : out STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (7 downto 0));
end dot_product ;
```